# select option while option value equals another class's value via JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to create a jquery function that if one drop down value equals the value of another class, it is selected.

```
<input type="hidden" class="target" value="two people"></input>
<select id="source">
    <option value="one person">One Person</option>
    <option value="two people">Two People</option>
    <option value="three people">Three People</option>
</select>
```

In the above case, Two People is selected. Because I used an iterated method to generate the select, I can not apply classes to option values. Is this doable without classes in options? Cheers.

Comment: Can you clearify your problem in more details. what does it means "if one drop down value equals the value of another class" ?

Answer (score 3):

Try this function 
http://jsfiddle.net/9z5N5/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       var target = $('input.target').eq(0).val();

    $('#source option').each(function(){
          var option = $(this);
          if( $(this).attr('value')== target ) option.attr('selected', 'selected');
    })

});
```

Comment: The only thing I'd suggest is using `option.attr('value')...` in your `if` since you've already retrieved `$(this)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(function(){
    var $select = $('#source'), $hidden = $select.prev();
    $select.val($hidden.val())
    $('#source').change(function(){
        $hidden.val($(this).val())
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/A7VjG/)

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/89Mzh/)

```
$("#source").val($(".target:first").val());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#source").val($(".target").val());
});
```